# Segmentation fault when reading command line arguments

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<zlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char *path=NULL;
   size_t size;
   int index ;
   printf("\nArgument count is = %d", argc);
   printf ("\nThe 0th argument to the file is %s", argv[0]);
   path = getcwd(path, size);
   printf("\nThe current working directory is = %s", path);
   if (argc <= 1)
   {
      printf("\nUsage: ./output filename1 filename2 ...");
   }
   else if (argc > 1)
   {
      for (index = 1; index <= argc;index++)
      {
            printf("\n File name entered is = %s", argv[index]);
            strcat(path,argv[index]);
            printf("\n The complete path of the file name is = %s", path);
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

In the above code, here is the output that I get while running the code:

```
$ ./output test.txt

Argument count is = 2
The 0th argument to the file is ./output
The current working directory is = /home/welcomeuser
 File name entered is = test.txt
 The complete path of the file name is = /home/welcomeusertest.txt
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Can anyone please me understand why I am getting a core dumped error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are going off the end of `argv` by saying `index <= argc`.  That should be `index < argc`.  Remember, array indexes go from *zero* to *one less than the length of the array*.

(You're correct to start at `1`, because `argv[0]` is the program name.)

Answer (score 4):

The `strcat` is not valid.  It is attempting to concatenate data to a buffer returned by the C runtime lib call.  You need to use your own buffer.  And you need to use free() on the buffer returned by getcwd() in the way that you are using it (passing in NULL causes it to allocate memory).

Comment: Hi Mark,

Can you please elaborate on your observation. I am a newbie to working on string operations and file operations on C. Any good resource to help me understand what you have pointed will be highly appreciated.

Regards,
darkie

Comment: @darkie: I was looking at the man page on a linux box and it indicates that getcwd allocates a buffer with malloc if the given buffer is NULL.  (http://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd).  It appears to be dependent on the version, though.  The returned buffer, though, would likely not be long enough for new data to be appended.  The strcat would add new data to that buffer and overwrite the the allocated space.

Answer (score 3):

`getcwd()` allocates a buffer for `path` of the size equal to `size`. You did not initialize the `size` variable. Set it large enough to hold the whole path AND the name, and this should work. If the buffer is not large enough, the `strcat()` will write past the end of the buffer, overwriting other values on the stack (possibly including the function return pointer, which would cause a segfault on `return`).

Also, `getcwd()` uses `malloc()` to allocate the buffer you assign to `path`. It would be nice to `free()` this buffer when you're done with it. Though this is not strictly necessary at the end of the program - as the system will reclaim the memory anyway.

There are also some logic errors in your code. Firstly, the `argv` array indices range from 0 to `argc`-1. Your `for` loop exit condition makes you read *one element past the end of the `argv` array*.

Note that the `strcat()` will append a new parameter each iteration *to the result of the previous iteration*. This means that invoking `/home$ ./output foo bar baz` would end up with:

```
The complete path of the file name is = /home/foo
The complete path of the file name is = /home/foobar
The complete path of the file name is = /home/foobarbaz
```

Which is probably not what you want :). (omitted irrelevant lines of the output).

Comment: @Fred Larson:
Just searched the manpage - you're right. Though that's a nonstandard glibc extension. Now this explains why did it not segfault right at the beginning ;).

Answer (score 2):

Although the answers about `strcat` are valid, given the point at which your program is crashing the issue is a NULL pointer deference because you use `<= argc` and not `< argc`.

In C, `argv[argc]` is a NULL pointer.

Answer (score 1):

`strcat(path,argv[index])` is adding data to a buffer that's not large enough to hold the additional data.

You should pass in a `size` value that will ensure the buffer is large enough. You're also not initializing `size`, so you really don't know what size buffer will be returned (all this is assuming that you're using the GNU libc version of `getcwd()` which will allocate a buffer if you pass in NULL).

Comment: Apparently there are at least 2 bugs in your code. RichieHindle, Donal Fellows and Charles Bailey have identified another serious problem.

Comment: Hi Michael,

I am new to string and file operations in C. Any good resource to help me understand what needs to be done here will be highly appreciated.
Regards,
darkie

Comment: K & R C book is still the gold standard.

Answer (score 1):

You're reading off the end of `argv`. Don't do that. Stop at the `argc-1`'th argument.